# Laravel project folder permission

Tags: laravel, permissions, vps

I have a problem with my Laravel project on VPS. Locally everything works fine, but on VPS sometimes folder permission changes and web site stops to work. I don't know what causes this problem and what should I do?

Every time I have to fix with this code:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /data/web/website.com
```

Comment: How do you deploy your code to the vps? With root user?

Comment: Yes with root user. My knowledge of VPS is very low...

Comment: if you are deploying with root user this means all the files will be "owned" by the root, and your web server will not be able to write on some folders like `storage`. try and deploy with a regular user

Comment: BTW, are you deploying with git with something else?

Comment: That's the problem. If you modify with the root user, you have to set the permissions by hand.

Comment: Yes I work with GIT. Everytime I pull something I change project folder permission to web user. But as I wrote sometimes it changes back to root user and website stops working.

Comment: do you have any other user in your server other that root? try using it to run git and see if the situation changes

Answer (score 0):

There may be some script which is rewriting the permissions for your folder. Go with the .htaccess file that will definately work.